# bootstrap modal inside php echo and JQuery .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have index.php which calls other test.php using jQuery and loads the contents in one div tag.

But if I put modal in `echo` of **test.php** it doesn't work.
Modal does not open.

Here is my **index.php**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="try"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function loadUnSolved(){
      $("#try").load("test.php");
    }
    $(document).ready(loadUnSolved());
  </script>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo '
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal12">Otryl</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal12" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
?>
```

I think the problem is in `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

Index.php :

```
<script>
    function loadUnSolved(){
        $("#try").load("test.php");
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){loadUnSolved()});
</script>
```

test.php :(you missed the # symbol)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal12">Otryl</button>
```

Comment: Seriously man :( Working fine now. Don't know how i missed that But why it's needed to have it like function(){loadUnSolved()} ?

Answer (score 0):

you need add a closure

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  loadUnSolved();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please also explain why this works.